# word2vec - get nearest words

Tags: tensorflow, word2vec

Reading the tensorflow word2vec model output how can I output the words related to a specific word ?

Reading the src : https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r0.11/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/word2vec/word2vec_basic.py can view how the image is plotted.

But is there a data structure (e.g dictionary) created as part of training the model that allows to access nearest n words closest to given word ?
For example if word2vec generated image :

[image]

image src: https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/tutorials/word2vec/index.html

In this image the words 'to , he , it' are contained in same cluster, is there a function which takes as input 'to' and outputs 'he , it' (in this case n=2) ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This approach apply to word2vec in general. If you can save the word2vec in text/binary file like google/[GloVe](http://nlp.stanford.edu/projects/glove/) word vector. Then what you need is just the [gensim](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/word2vec.html#module-gensim.models.word2vec).

To install:

[Via github](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim)

Python code:

```
from gensim.models import Word2Vec

gmodel=Word2Vec.load_word2vec_format(fname)
ms=gmodel.most_similar('good',10)
for x in ms:
    print x[0],x[1]
```

However this will search all the words to give the results, there are approximate nearest neighbor (ANN) which will give you the result faster but with a trade off in accuracy.

In the latest gensim, [annoy](https://github.com/spotify/annoy) is used to perform the ANN, see this [notebooks](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/develop/docs/notebooks/annoytutorial.ipynb) for more information.

[Flann is another library for Approximate Nearest Neighbors.](https://github.com/mariusmuja/flann)

Answer (score 5):

I will assume that you don't want to use gensim, and would prefer to stick with tensorflow. In that case, I'll offer two options

## Option 1 - Tensorboard:

If you are just trying to do this from an exploratory standpoint, I would suggest using Tensorboard's embedding visualizer to search for the closest embeddings. It provides a cool interface and you can use both cosine and euclidian distances with a set number of neighbors.

[image: Tensorboard's embedding visualizer]

[Link to Tensorflow documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.1/get_started/embedding_viz)

## Option 2 - Direct Calculation

Within the word2vec_basic.py file, there is an example of how they are calculating closest words, and you could go ahead and use that if you mess with the function a little bit. The following is found in the graph itself:

```
# Compute the cosine similarity between minibatch examples and all embeddings.
norm = tf.sqrt(tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(embeddings), 1, keep_dims=True))
normalized_embeddings = embeddings / norm
valid_embeddings = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(
  normalized_embeddings, valid_dataset)
similarity = tf.matmul(
  valid_embeddings, normalized_embeddings, transpose_b=True)
```

Then, during training (every 10000 steps) they run this next bit of code (while the session is active). When they call `similarity.eval()` it is getting the literal numpy array evaluation of the similarity tensor in the graph.

```
# Note that this is expensive (~20% slowdown if computed every 500 steps)
if step % 10000 == 0:
  sim = similarity.eval()
  for i in xrange(valid_size):
    valid_word = reverse_dictionary[valid_examples[i]]
    top_k = 8 # number of nearest neighbors
    nearest = (-sim[i, :]).argsort()[1:top_k+1]
    log_str = "Nearest to %s:" % valid_word
    for k in xrange(top_k):
      close_word = reverse_dictionary[nearest[k]]
      log_str = "%s %s," % (log_str, close_word)
    print(log_str)
```

If you want to adapt this for yourself, you will have to do some finessing with changing `reverse_dictionary[valid_examples[i]]` to be the word/words idxs that you want to get the k-closest words for.

Answer (score 2):

Get [gensim](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/) and use [similar_by_word](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/word2vec.html) method on `gensim.models.Word2Vec` model.

`similar_by_word` takes 3 parameters,

1. The input word
2. n - for top n similar words (optional, default=10)
3. restrict_vocab (optional, default=None)

**Example**

```
import gensim, nltk

class FileToSent(object):
   """A class to load a text file efficiently """   
    def __init__(self, filename):
        self.filename = filename
        # To remove stop words (optional)
        self.stop = set(nltk.corpus.stopwords.words('english'))

    def __iter__(self):
        for line in open(self.filename, 'r'):
            ll = [i for i in unicode(line, 'utf-8').lower().split() if i not in self.stop]
            yield ll
```

Then depending on your input sentences (sentence_file.txt),

```
sentences = FileToSent('sentence_file.txt')
model = gensim.models.Word2Vec(sentences=sentences, min_count=2, hs=1)
print model.similar_by_word('hack', 2) # Get two most similar words to 'hack'
# [(u'debug', 0.967338502407074), (u'patch', 0.952264130115509)] (Output specific to my dataset)
```